# TypeError: module.PosModel is undefined

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo, typeerror, point-of-sale

I inherited on the point_of_sale models.js file in order to add a model. This by following code:

```
openerp.dewieuw = function(instance, local) { //module is instance.point_of_sale
var module = instance.point_of_sale;
var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;
var _t = instance.web._t;
var round_di = instance.web.round_decimals;
var round_pr = instance.web.round_precision

alert(instance.point_of_sale)
alert(module)
module.PosModel = module.PosModel.extend({

    models: [
    {
        model:  'res.users',
        fields: ['name','company_id'],
        ids:    function(self){ return [self.session.uid]; },
        loaded: function(self,users){ self.user = users[0]; },
    },{ 
        model:  'res.company',
        fields: [ 'currency_id', 'email', 'website', 'company_registry', 'vat', 'name', 'phone', 'partner_id' , 'country_id', 'tax_calculation_rounding_method'],
        ids:    function(self){ return [self.user.company_id[0]] },
        loaded: function(self,companies){ self.company = companies[0]; },
    },{
        model:  'decimal.precision',
        fields: ['name','digits'],
        loaded: function(self,dps){
            self.dp  = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < dps.length; i++) {
                self.dp[dps[i].name] = dps[i].digits;
            }
        },
    },{ 
        model:  'product.uom',
        fields: [],
        domain: null,
        loaded: function(self,units){
            self.units = units;
            var units_by_id = {};
            for(var i = 0, len = units.length; i < len; i++){
                units_by_id[units[i].id] = units[i];
                units[i].groupable = ( units[i].category_id[0] === 1 );
                units[i].is_unit   = ( units[i].id === 1 );
            }
            self.units_by_id = units_by_id;
        }
    },{
        model:  'res.users',
        fields: ['name','ean13'],
        domain: null,
        loaded: function(self,users){ self.users = users; },
    },{
        model:  'res.partner',
        fields: ['name','street','city','state_id','country_id','vat','phone','zip','mobile','email','ean13','write_date','nieuwsbrief','klantgroep','lang'],
        domain: [['customer','=',true]],
        loaded: function(self,partners){
            self.partners = partners;
            self.db.add_partners(partners);
        },
    },{
        model:  'res.lang',
        fields: ['name', 'code'],
        loaded: function(self,langs){
            self.langs = langs;
        },
    },{
        model:  'klantgroep',
        fields: ['name'],
        loaded: function(self,klantgroepen){
            self.klantgroepen = klantgroepen;
        },
    },{
        model:  'res.country',
        fields: ['name'],
        loaded: function(self,countries){
            self.countries = countries;
            self.company.country = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
                if (countries[i].id === self.company.country_id[0]){
                    self.company.country = countries[i];
                }
            }
        },
    },{
        model:  'account.tax',
        fields: ['name','amount', 'price_include', 'include_base_amount', 'type', 'child_ids', 'child_depend', 'include_base_amount'],
        domain: null,
        loaded: function(self, taxes){
            self.taxes = taxes;
            self.taxes_by_id = {};
            _.each(taxes, function(tax){
                self.taxes_by_id[tax.id] = tax;
            });
            _.each(self.taxes_by_id, function(tax) {
                tax.child_taxes = {};
                _.each(tax.child_ids, function(child_tax_id) {
                    tax.child_taxes[child_tax_id] = self.taxes_by_id[child_tax_id];
                });
            });
        },
    },{
        model:  'pos.session',
        fields: ['id', 'journal_ids','name','user_id','config_id','start_at','stop_at','sequence_number','login_number'],
        domain: function(self){ return [['state','=','opened'],['user_id','=',self.session.uid]]; },
        loaded: function(self,pos_sessions){
            self.pos_session = pos_sessions[0]; 

            var orders = self.db.get_orders();
            for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
                self.pos_session.sequence_number = Math.max(self.pos_session.sequence_number, orders[i].data.sequence_number+1);
            }
        },
    },{
        model: 'pos.config',
        fields: [],
        domain: function(self){ return [['id','=', self.pos_session.config_id[0]]]; },
        loaded: function(self,configs){
            self.config = configs[0];
            self.config.use_proxy = self.config.iface_payment_terminal || 
                                    self.config.iface_electronic_scale ||
                                    self.config.iface_print_via_proxy  ||
                                    self.config.iface_scan_via_proxy   ||
                                    self.config.iface_cashdrawer;

            self.barcode_reader.add_barcode_patterns({
                'product':  self.config.barcode_product,
                'cashier':  self.config.barcode_cashier,
                'client':   self.config.barcode_customer,
                'weight':   self.config.barcode_weight,
                'discount': self.config.barcode_discount,
                'price':    self.config.barcode_price,
            });

            if (self.config.company_id[0] !== self.user.company_id[0]) {
                throw new Error(_t("Error: The Point of Sale User must belong to the same company as the Point of Sale. You are probably trying to load the point of sale as an administrator in a multi-company setup, with the administrator account set to the wrong company."));
            }
        },
    },{
        model: 'stock.location',
        fields: [],
        ids:    function(self){ return [self.config.stock_location_id[0]]; },
        loaded: function(self, locations){ self.shop = locations[0]; },
    },{
        model:  'product.pricelist',
        fields: ['currency_id'],
        ids:    function(self){ return [self.config.pricelist_id[0]]; },
        loaded: function(self, pricelists){ self.pricelist = pricelists[0]; },
    },{
        model: 'res.currency',
        fields: ['symbol','position','rounding','accuracy'],
        ids:    function(self){ return [self.pricelist.currency_id[0]]; },
        loaded: function(self, currencies){
            self.currency = currencies[0];
            if (self.currency.rounding > 0) {
                self.currency.decimals = Math.ceil(Math.log(1.0 / self.currency.rounding) / Math.log(10));
            } else {
                self.currency.decimals = 0;
            }

        },
    },{
        model: 'product.packaging',
        fields: ['ean','product_tmpl_id'],
        domain: null,
        loaded: function(self, packagings){ 
            self.db.add_packagings(packagings);
        },
    },{
        model:  'pos.category',
        fields: ['id','name','parent_id','child_id','image'],
        domain: null,
        loaded: function(self, categories){
            self.db.add_categories(categories);
        },
    },{
        model:  'product.product',
        fields: ['display_name', 'list_price','price','pos_categ_id', 'taxes_id', 'ean13', 'default_code', 
                 'to_weight', 'uom_id', 'uos_id', 'uos_coeff', 'mes_type', 'description_sale', 'description',
                 'product_tmpl_id'],
        domain: [['sale_ok','=',true],['available_in_pos','=',true]],
        context: function(self){ return { pricelist: self.pricelist.id, display_default_code: false }; },
        loaded: function(self, products){
            self.db.add_products(products);
        },
    },{
        model:  'account.bank.statement',
        fields: ['account_id','currency','journal_id','state','name','user_id','pos_session_id'],
        domain: function(self){ return [['state', '=', 'open'],['pos_session_id', '=', self.pos_session.id]]; },
        loaded: function(self, bankstatements, tmp){
            self.bankstatements = bankstatements;

            tmp.journals = [];
            _.each(bankstatements,function(statement){
                tmp.journals.push(statement.journal_id[0]);
            });
        },
    },{
        model:  'account.journal',
        fields: [],
        domain: function(self,tmp){ return [['id','in',tmp.journals]]; },
        loaded: function(self, journals){
            self.journals = journals;

            // associate the bank statements with their journals. 
            var bankstatements = self.bankstatements;
            for(var i = 0, ilen = bankstatements.length; i < ilen; i++){
                for(var j = 0, jlen = journals.length; j < jlen; j++){
                    if(bankstatements[i].journal_id[0] === journals[j].id){
                        bankstatements[i].journal = journals[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            self.cashregisters = bankstatements;
        },
    },{
        label: 'fonts',
        loaded: function(self){
            var fonts_loaded = new $.Deferred();

            // Waiting for fonts to be loaded to prevent receipt printing
            // from printing empty receipt while loading Inconsolata
            // ( The font used for the receipt ) 
            waitForWebfonts(['Lato','Inconsolata'], function(){
                fonts_loaded.resolve();
            });

            // The JS used to detect font loading is not 100% robust, so
            // do not wait more than 5sec
            setTimeout(function(){
                fonts_loaded.resolve();
            },5000);

            return fonts_loaded;
        },
    },{
        label: 'pictures',
        loaded: function(self){
            self.company_logo = new Image();
            var  logo_loaded = new $.Deferred();
            self.company_logo.onload = function(){
                var img = self.company_logo;
                var ratio = 1;
                var targetwidth = 300;
                var maxheight = 150;
                if( img.width !== targetwidth ){
                    ratio = targetwidth / img.width;
                }
                if( img.height * ratio > maxheight ){
                    ratio = maxheight / img.height;
                }
                var width  = Math.floor(img.width * ratio);
                var height = Math.floor(img.height * ratio);
                var c = document.createElement('canvas');
                    c.width  = width;
                    c.height = height
                var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.drawImage(self.company_logo,0,0, width, height);

                self.company_logo_base64 = c.toDataURL();
                logo_loaded.resolve();
            };
            self.company_logo.onerror = function(){
                logo_loaded.reject();
            };
                self.company_logo.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            self.company_logo.src = '/web/binary/company_logo' +'?_'+Math.random();

            return logo_loaded;
        },
    },
    ],

});
    module.ClientListScreenWidget = module.ClientListScreenWidget.extend({

        // what happens when we save the changes on the client edit form -> we fetch the fields, sanitize them,
        // send them to the backend for update, and call saved_client_details() when the server tells us the
        // save was successfull.
        save_client_details: function(partner) {
            var self = this;

            var fields = {}
            this.$('.client-details-contents .detail').each(function(idx,el){
                fields[el.name] = el.value;

                if(el.name=='nieuwsbrief'){
                    fields[el.name] = el.checked;
                }
            });



            if (!fields.name) {
                this.pos_widget.screen_selector.show_popup('error',{
                    message: _t('A Customer Name Is Required'),
                });
                return;
            }

            if (this.uploaded_picture) {
                fields.image = this.uploaded_picture;
            }

            fields.id           = partner.id || false;
            fields.country_id   = fields.country_id || false;
            fields.ean13        = fields.ean13 ? this.pos.barcode_reader.sanitize_ean(fields.ean13) : false; 

            new instance.web.Model('res.partner').call('create_from_ui',[fields]).then(function(partner_id){
                self.saved_client_details(partner_id);
            },function(err,event){
                event.preventDefault();
                self.pos_widget.screen_selector.show_popup('error',{
                    'message':_t('Error: Could not Save Changes'),
                    'comment':_t('Your Internet connection is probably down.'),
                });
            });
        },

    });


}
```

This worked like a charm. But now I wanted to inherit on the website_sale.js file so I added some test code to this file. And now I always get this error:

> TypeError: module.PosModel is undefined

I deleted this test code, but still the error occurs. Any ideas? I also placed my whole module back to a backup were everything worked fine, but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added point_of_sale dependency in website_sale module **openerp**.py file ?

If not, please add it and try again.

Comment: Yes I did, like I mentioned this worked before. But by adding some JS code and deleting it, this stopped working.

Comment: Can you send that file, so I can check it.

Comment: Hi I updated my question with the code in it. Thanks

Comment: Please use the openerp.website_sale instead of openerp.dewieuw in first line when you add code in website_sale.js file. It is the name of module.